# Web fonts not working in all IE versions

Tags: web, fonts

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Futura Std';
src: url('../fonts/FuturaStd-Light.eot');
src: url('../fonts/FuturaStd-Light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('../fonts/FuturaStd-Light.woff') format('woff'),
url('../fonts/FuturaStd-Light.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: 300;
font-style: normal;
}
```

- List item

  Am getting issue to loading fonts. My path is fine but still not loading
  fonts in IE all versions

Comment: Please any one help me in this. All browsers are working fine only All IE versions getting problem..THANK yOU

Comment: Any one can you guys help me out for IE Versions....